# Is the sys_call_table read protected in 4.8 kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

I use the simple sys_call_table rewrite to
log all execve calls in a system.

When moving to Ubuntu 16.10 with a 4.8 kernel this
mechanism suddenly stopped to work. In 16.04 with
a 4.6 kernel it was working.

```
    1: write_cr0 (read_cr0 () & (~ 0x10000));

    2: original_execve = (void *)syscall_table[__NR_execve];
    3: syscall_table[__NR_execve] = (unsigned long)&new_execve;

    4: write_cr0 (read_cr0 () | 0x10000);
```

The page fault already happens when reading the old entry, that is line 2.
To retrive the sys_call_table address I use:

```
sudo cat /boot/System.map-`uname -r` | grep -e '\ssys_call_table' | awk '{ print $1}' )"
```

Code is from: https://github.com/eiselekd/shinterposer/tree/master/mod

Does anyone know what happened? Maybe some 
protection mechanism has been introduced?

Comment: Found a solution so far: I recompiled the 4.8 kernel and exported symbol sys_call_table as well
as removed the const specifier. That way I can reference sys_call_table directly from the module. Still not shure still why it crashed with the version that worked for 4.6 though. Is the linking for read-only sections changed?

Comment: You can find a good summary of all the mitigations Linux has implemented (up to 4.2, anyway) in [this](https://outflux.net/slides/2016/lss/kspp.pdf) presentation.

Comment: Thanks. A question: Is there a way to actually get the syscall table address back if kaslr is present? I guess that would be considered a exploit but anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be ***Address Space Layout Randomization (kASLR)*** on the syscall table taking
place by default in the 4.8 kernel. When declaring the sys_call_table symbol as exported and linking against it directly from a module the address for sys_call_table is changing for each boot. 
The address from /boot/System.map-xxx is useless.

To disable kaslr in ubuntu 16.10 kernel 4.8 one can add

```
nokaslr
```

to the kernel command line.